# Create pnb file and save with python

Tags: python, numpy, save, jupyter

I have a dataset where each rows are a 'column' dimension datapoint, and I want to process it and save each datapoint to a .pnb file . So I would need a snippet that creates a new file and saves in it.

For now I got this, but I am having trouble with the path file. Should it be relative to where my notebook is, or from C: ?

```
y = full_dataset[1,:]
z = np.save('./data/folder1/2.pnb',y)
```

Comment: From the [`numpy.save`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) docstring: "Save an array to a binary file in NumPy ``.npy`` format."  What is a .pnb file?

Comment: Paths can either be relative, or full. relative path depends on where you executing the code. using 'os.getcwd()' will get you your current working dir, need to be relative to that. Or you can use the full path.

Comment: Thanks guys, should have been .npy, the path was fine but didn't know about the .getcwd() command, so cheers! Reckon I should edit the question or just delete it? the code works when changing .pnb to .npy